# Create a command whose delimiters are not curly braces

Tags: macros, listings

Whenever I want to write an inline piece of code of LaTeX by using the `listings` package, I have to use the following command:

```
\lstinline[language={[latex]tex}, keywordstyle={\color[HTML]{101094}}]|\begin{document}|
\lstinline[language={[latex]tex}, keywordstyle={\color[HTML]{101094}}]|\end{document}|
\lstinline[language={[latex]tex}, keywordstyle={\color[HTML]{101094}}]|{\Huge test text}|
```

Note that the text to be typeset is `\begin{document}` and is enclosed within two vertical bar characters (i.e. `|`) in order to accept underscores and braces within the command argument.
What I want to do is to create a command that would make me not to type all the options from the `\lstinline` command

```
\LaTeXLST|\begin{document}|
\LaTeXLST|\end{document}|
\LaTeXLST|{\Huge test text}|
```

**Note 1** I tried to do the following with no avail.

```
\newcommand\LaTeXLST[1]{\lstinline[language={[latex]tex}, keywordstyle={\color[HTML]{101094}}]|#1|}
```

**Note 2** I thought in creating an `lst` style that would define the `language` and the `keywordstyle`, but the idea of creating a command is more appealing since it requires less keypressings.

```
\lstinline[style=mylatex]|\begin{document}|
```

**Note 3** I know LateX only accepts braces as argument delimiters but I want to mimick the behavior of the `\lstinline` package in order to accept vertical bars as command arguments delimiters. I've been reading the documentation on the `listings` package and you can use "any character not in the code" (p. 4) to delimit the code.

The reason I want to do this is because I'm working on a guide on LaTeX for my fellow classmates. For this reason, I need to constantly typeset code listings and inline LaTeX code within the document. I am using the `listings` because I can define an style and share that style among all the pieces of code that were typeset through the `listings` commands (i.e. `\lstinline`, `\lstinputlisting`, the `lstlisting` environment).

Comment: Scanning the argument breaks verbatim.  Just don't scan it: `\newcommand\LaTeXLST{\lstinline[language={[latex]tex}, keywordstyle={\color[HTML]{101094}}]}`

Comment: You are right. That work as intended, therefore you have answered the question throughly. However, a new question arises. I've posted it [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519681/use-argument-from-lstinline-twice-in-a-user-defined-command).