# Use argument from lstinline twice in a user defined command

Tags: macros, listings

I'm writing a document (that uses the `listings` package) which aims to show the output of some LaTeX commands. I want to create a command that would allow me to typeset the command inline and its output in a single line. Writing

```
\noindent lorem
\\\LaTeXShow|{\Huge test text}|
\\ipsum
```

would display the following

[image]

The reason I want to do this is because I am writing a guide on LaTeX for my fellow ċlassmates and I want to show the output of having executed some LaTeX commands. The code snippet presented below is a minimum working example that represents some of the content I am currently writing

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\LaTeXShow}{\lstinline[language = {[latex]tex}, keywordstyle = {\color[HTML]{101094}}, basicstyle = {\ttfamily}]}

\begin{document}
    \noindent\LaTeXShow|{\Huge test text}| displays {\Huge test text}
    \\\LaTeXShow|{\Huge test text}| displays {\Huge test text}
    \\\LaTeXShow|{\Huge test text}| displays {\Huge test text}
    \\\LaTeXShow|{\huge test text}| displays {\huge test text}
    \\\LaTeXShow|{\LARGE test text}| displays {\LARGE test text}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, there is a pattern among the lines of the body of the document. If the desired command existed, then the document would look like this

```
\begin{document}
    \noindent\LaTeXShow|{\Huge test text}|
    \\\LaTeXShow|{\Huge test text}|
    \\\LaTeXShow|{\Huge test text}|
    \\\LaTeXShow|{\huge test text}|
    \\\LaTeXShow|{\LARGE test text}|
\end{document}
```

and the output would be

[image]

**Note** The command must use the `lstinline` command from the `listings` package. The reason behind this is because of the style options that package offers.

Comment: [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/506038/command-to-display-and-execute-code-math-formulae) answered my question thoroughly. In this scenario, the command would be `\NewDocumentCommand\LaTeXShow{v}{\lstinline[language = {[latex]tex}, keywordstyle = {\color[HTML]{101094}}]{#1} displays \scantokens{#1\noexpand}}` and I can call that macro by using vertical bar characters `\LaTeXShow|{\Huge test text}|`.

Comment: I've added a comment on the original answer there, you should really use `\scantokens{#1\noexpand}\relax` instead, or switch to the `expl3` version in my answer.